# Not able to symbolicate crash log using 'symbolicatecrash' command however atos works

Tags: ios, macos, crash, symbolicatecrash

I want to symbolicate the crash log on mac but symbolicatecrash shows me the same crash log every time. I have tried following stuff

1) made sure that .app, .dSym and crash logs all reside in the same folder.

2) Also made sure that symbols are indexed and seen by spot light using this command
 mdfind 'com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids = *

3) Made sure that uuid of symbol file and crash log match.

When I run atos command I am able to fetch symbol information, but still symbolicatecrsh fails to symbolicate it

```
atos -arch i386 -o test 0x00002ddb
test crashHit:] (in test) (testViewController.m:43)

symbolicatecrash -A -v test.crash test
```

This crash log was generated by an app running on simulator not on device. Can it make any diff?

output: - 
otool path is 'xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool'
atos path is 'xcrun -sdk iphoneos atos'
Symbolicating...
27445 characters read.
Use of uninitialized value $pat in regexp compilation at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash line 500.
Use of uninitialized value $image{"uuid"} in lc at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash line 509.
Use of uninitialized value $bundlename in hash element at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash line 517.
Use of uninitialized value $bundlename in hash element at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash line 535.
….
….

Use of uninitialized value $first_bundle in hash element at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash line 887.
Use of uninitialized value $first_bundle in anonymous hash ({}) at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash line 887.
1 binary images referenced:
        (Use of uninitialized value in print at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash line 894.
)

OS Version 10.7.3 Build 11D50b
0 binary images remain after pruning:

Symbol directory paths:
Symbol directory paths:  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.1/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.2.1/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.2.2/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.2/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.1/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.2/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.1/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1 (9B176)/Symbols /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/Latest/Symbols
Symbol directory path(s) not found for 10.7.3 (11D50b):
Finding Symbols:
done.
0 binary images were found.
Process:         CrittercismExample [2250]
Path:            /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/*/CrittercismExample.app/CrittercismExample
Identifier:      CrittercismExample
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [118]

Date/Time:       2012-04-27 02:27:47.003 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50b)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 238.2, iPhone OS 4.3.2 (iPhone/8H7)
iPhone Simulator 238.2, iPhone OS 4.3.2 (iPhone/8H7)

abort() called

Comment: Without any error message details from symbolicatecrash it is impossible to give an answer. Does the uuid of the app binary match the others too?

Comment: uuid of dsym file also match the one in crash log. here is the complete dump from crash log.

Comment: Where did you get `symbolicatecrash` from?  I don't have it on my system (Lion with Xcode 4.3.2 + command line tools).

Comment: System symbols won't work, since the Simulator symbols are not at the place the script is searching them. There is no info available on the app symbols in the log you posted. Why don't you run the demo app on the device instead? Simulator crashes are not helpful in general if you don't attach the debugger to it.